# Custom Items in Lists in C# forms?

Tags: c#, forms, list, items

I'm a bit new to the C#-form app developing and I want know, what's the best way around at making a control that holds a list of horizontal items. In which each of these items are horizontally ruled to it's parent control, contain a thumbnail to the left and a large text block to the right of image and a smaller text block underneath that. So basically this isn't a predefined control I can find in the toolbox. Any ideas?

Comment: this would be cake in WPF....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could lay this out with Panels in form controls,  or with WrapPanel and StackPanel in WPF.

In WindowsForms, I would create a user control that held the correct layout for a single item, then make a list of them at run time.

In WPF I would use a List control, but set the layout template to use WrapPanels and StackPanels.

WPf is the better solution long term if you don't have to coexist with winforms

Comment: Alright I assume this user-control can be placed nicely inside the panel? I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: mmm,you could do it that way, but I would just make an ListBox item template--much easier.